# Click file on sidebar to open - instead of doubleclick

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to modify TestCafé behaviour so that when you click on a filename on the sidebar, the file is opened, instead of requiring doubleclick?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is not currently configurable. We have plans to customize some of its aspects, but not in the immediate future.